# TX decode failed Separator is missing at the end of an output map: iostream error

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bip174-psbt

```
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:18332/wallet/w3"

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}

def combinetx():

    payload = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"1.0\",\r\n \"id\": \"test\",\r\n  \"method\": \"combinepsbt\",\r\n  \"params\": [[\"" + str(round_spsbt_list[0]) + "\",\"" + str(round_spsbt_list[1]) + "\",\"" + str(round_spsbt_list[2]) + "\",\"" + str(round_spsbt_list[3]) + "\",\"" + str(round_spsbt_list) + "\"]]\r\n}"
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    combined_psbt = response.json()

    return combined_psbt
    
if __name__=="__main__":

    round_spsbt_list = []

    round_spsbt_list.append("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")

    round_spsbt_list.append("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")

    round_spsbt_list.append("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")

    round_spsbt_list.append("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")

    round_spsbt_list.append("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")

    ctx = combinetx()
    print(ctx)
```

What is the reason for this error and how to fix it? I understand error says 'separator is missing at the end of output map', however I checked everything and couldn't find anything wrong with the code including other functions.

Error:

```
{'result': None, 'error': {'code': -22, 'message': 'TX decode failed Separator is missing at the end of an output map: iostream error'}, 'id': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the PSBT is malformed and missing the separator required at the end of each section within the PSBT. This error usually comes up when the last output map is missing the separator. A common cause of this is to accidentally miss the last character or two of the PSBT when selecting it to be copy and pasted into another program.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to add list index for last PSBT so `str(round_spsbt_list[4])` and using new PSBTs to combine fixed it.